# C malloc of struct execution error

Tags: c, struct, segmentation-fault, malloc, free

I do not understand why I can use malloc with **struct var **tableauVariables**, but I receve an error with **struct zone **tableauZonesMemoireLibres**.

When debuging I receve :

> At C:\Users\Onel\Desktop\test\test.c:33 Program received signal
>   SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.

My code :

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void tabInit(), tabDelete();

struct zone {
    int pos;
    int taille;
};

struct var {
    char id[10];
    struct zone  tableau;
};

struct var **tableauVariables;
struct zone **tableauZonesMemoireLibres;
int tailleMemoire= 10;

int main () {

    tabInit();

    tabDelete();

    return 0;
}

void tabInit() {
    tableauVariables = (struct var**) malloc(sizeof(struct var) * tailleMemoire);
    tableauVariables[0] = NULL;

    tableauZonesMemoireLibres = (struct zone**) malloc(sizeof(struct zone) * tailleMemoire);
    tableauZonesMemoireLibres[0]->pos = 0; //Line 33 segmentation fault
    tableauZonesMemoireLibres[0]->taille = tailleMemoire;
    tableauZonesMemoireLibres[1] = NULL;

    return;
}

void tabDelete() {
    int i;

    for(i=0; tableauZonesMemoireLibres[i] != NULL; i++)
        free(tableauZonesMemoireLibres[i]);
    free(tableauZonesMemoireLibres);

    for(i=0; tableauVariables[i] != NULL; i++)
        free(tableauVariables[i]);
    free(tableauVariables);
}
```

Comment: `tableauVariables = malloc(sizeof(struct var *) * tailleMemoire);` or simpler and more robust: `tableauVariables = malloc(tailleMemoire * sizeof *tableauVariables );`

Comment: Learn to use valgrind for things like this.

Comment: Learn the language before even touching a debugger. Debuggers will teach you nothing. BTW: `tableauZonesMemoireLibres` : similar error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You allocate an array, and cast it to a **.

This allocates an array of struct zone of size tailleMemoire.

```
tableauZonesMemoireLibres = (struct zone**) malloc(sizeof(struct zone) * tailleMemoire);
```

Maybe what you intended is

```
struct zone *tableauZonesMemoireLibres;
tableauZonesMemoireLibres = malloc(sizeof(struct zone) * tailleMemoire);
tableauZonesMemoireLibres[0].pos = 0; //Line 33 segmentation fault
tableauZonesMemoireLibres[0].taille = tailleMemoire;
```

Also, your tabDelete is totally wrong. You want one free foreach malloc:

```
void tabDelete() {
    free(tableauZonesMemoireLibres);
    free(tableauVariables);
}
```

On the other hand, if you really did want an array of pointers, then each element of that array needs to malloc'ed by itself.

Comment: Yes, I do want an array of pointers and you are right I forgot to malloc the first element before using it. Thanks